# Multicolumn form with checkboxes and text inputs is displayed wrong

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide screen in 3 equals columns and output 6 input fields in 2 lines so it's like 6 cells: 2 lines* 3 columns with label+input in the center of each cell. When I got to 4th I got the problem, it's appeared in 5th position instead of 4th:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="field1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">From</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">checkbox1
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">checkbox2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="field4" class="col-sm-4 control-label">To</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field4" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="field5" class="col-sm-4 control-label">To</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field5" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="field6" class="col-sm-4 control-label">To</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field6" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/My98o6loOHoKM9vLqn0H?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by "When i got to 4th i got the problem, its appeard in 5th position instead of 4th". 

From the demo on pinkr i do see an issue where you are not getting your 3 column layout.  This part can be fixed by adding class "pull-left" to each of your form-group divs.  Also, before your 4th .form-group, you should add a "<div class='clearfix'></div>"
http://plnkr.co/edit/1YWY3N7UaMMzPBYFG2hb?p=preview

Comment: 1 row = 12 col : One way is to wrap your 3 element in one div.row :  http://plnkr.co/edit/wSqeQKnHbeVL0yQHziwa?p=preview

Comment: @TheLittlePig Well thanks, that solves the issue. Why it doesn't do this automatically? I have 6 elements of width 4, so 4th element should go in 13-15 position instead it goes in 16-18.

Answer (score 0):

add
 `.form-horizontal .form-group:after{
  display:inline-block;
}`
into your css file. That will solve your problem. But I recommend to use a different class name to do that, as the `form-horizontal` & `form-group` is bootstrap's built-in class :)

Comment: I'm already using form-horizontal & form-group and it's not working. Look at the source code I provided